# Type checking in a Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, typechecking, mypy, pytype

I am trying to use a static type checking tool to check for wrong assignment to a variable. E.g., assign a string to an int variable.

I tried **pytype** and **mypy**. Both didn't give me any warnings.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x : int = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.x = 'abc'
    print(a.x)
```

I expect a static type checking tool can give me a warning on the above line:

```py
a.x = 'abc'
```

Do I need to use some options or other helper tools to detect this kind of assignment statement?

Comment: Hey there. Which IDE environment are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when I copy your code and check it with mypy, I get the following result:

```
project\scratch.py:7: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
```

I found this by executing `mypy path/to/file.py`.

Internally, within Visual Studio Code, selecting mypy as the linter underlines the `a` variable and overlays the mypy error.

So I'm getting the warning error codes displayed correctly; maybe your IDE isn't set up to handle them.

**Note:** executing `python path/to/file.py` will not display the mypy error, most likely to keep the typing 'soft' - so that the code will still execute, and typing is more to 'hint', rather than stop the code:

> You can always use a Python interpreter to run your statically typed
> programs, even if they have type errors:
> $ python3 PROGRAM

[From the documentation](https://github.com/python/mypy).

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for other IDEs, but for Visual Studio Code (using Python 3.8.5)...

1. Install pylance (Microsoft's Python language server extension)
2. Add these two lines to settings.json:

   ```
   "python.languageServer":"Pylance",
   "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode" :"strict"
   ```
3. Note the following problems reported:

   ```
   (variable) x: None
      Cannot assign member "x" for type "A"
         Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to member "x" of class "A"
         Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "int"Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues) [3, 14]

   (variable) x: Literal['abc']
      Cannot assign member "x" for type "A"
         Expression of type "Literal['abc']" cannot be assigned to member "x" of class "A"
         "Literal['abc']" is incompatible with "int"Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues) [7, 7]
   ```